# Hacer que python imprima todas las excepciones en ingles

Tags: python

Actualmente mi instalación de python 2.7 imprime algunos, pero no todas los mensajes de error en español

```
socket.error: [Errno 10054] Se ha forzado la interrupci¾n de una conexi¾n existente por el host remoto
```

Como puedo hacer que todas las excepciones se muestren en ingles?

Answer (score 1):

A la vista de que te sale `interrupci¾n` en vez de `interrupción` creo que no me equivoco al pensar que estás en Windows.

Python no ofrece mecanismos para traducir los mensajes de sus excepciones, que vienen siempre en inglés. Aparentemente el mensaje de error en este caso es específico de Windows, que es quien maneja "por debajo" los sockets. Probablemente python, al desconocer las particularidades de la plataforma en que se está ejecutando, se limita a imprimir el código numérico de error y el mensaje explicativo que le reporta Windows.

Puedes cambiar el idioma por defecto de Windows, y seguramente eso cambiará el mensaje.

Puedes capturar la excepción `socket.error`, examinar la cadena del mensaje buscando cierto código numérico y elevar tú otra excepción con el mensaje traducido. Algo así:

```py
try:
     # Codigo que maneja sockets
except socket.error, e:
    if 'Errno 10054' in str(e):
        raise socket.error("[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host")
```

Pero mejor aún **no deberías hacer nada**. Se supone que los mensajes de excepción nunca han de llegar a ser visibles al usuario final, puesto que tu aplicación debe manejar esas excepciones de forma apropiada (salvo quizás durante la fase de desarrollo, en la que no es muy importante el idioma en que aparezcan).